# Is it possible to get FORMAT to ignore undefined format directives?

Tags: format, common-lisp

I wonder if it is possible to tell FORMAT to ignore undefined format directives. I have looked at the pages for FORMAT in the CLHS but I don't see anything.

What I am trying to do is to get FORMAT to ignore `~m` in a format string and just output `~m` instead of trying to replace it with something. My plan is that at that point I will call another function which knows what to do with with `~m`.

I guess a related question is then, is there a way to define a function to handle a format directive which is otherwise not defined?

In anticipation of some questions. (1) I guess a workaround would be to substitute a placeholder for `~m`, and then substitute it back in afterwards and keep going. I guess I'll do that if all else fails. (2) I guess another general strategy would be to call the other function first, to handle `~m`, then call FORMAT on the result. Unfortunately that other function recognizes some of the same directives, and barfs on others; it doesn't recognize only `~m` and ignore everything else.

Comment: Could you use `"~~m"` in the format string to generate `"~m"` in the output that is then fed to the other string processing function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a good idea, I guess that would work, although I was hoping to avoid modifying the control string.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own format directive with ~/name/, where name is the name of the function which is called. In your case you would have:

```
(format t "~/m/" 1)

(defun m (stream n colon-mod at-mod) 
   (format stream "~a" n)) ; or do something else with n
```

You still need to change the control string, but you can add a preprocessing step where "~m" is replaced by "~/m/".

Comment: The question of OA is not very understandable. You don't need `~m` because you are already now defining the function which does sth in place of `~m` with n. but thanks, didn't know that one can define own format directives.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way of doing that portably (implementations may let you do all sorts of magic).  I'd write a `quote-weird-tildes` and `dequote-weird-tildes` pair of functions and then write code like:

```
(defun format/qw (control &rest args)
  (declare (dynamic-extent args)
           (type string control))       ;can't be a function
  (dequote-weird-tildes
   (apply #'format nil (quote-weird-tildes control) args)))
```

Now you have a function which looks like `(format nil ...)` and is no harder to use than that.  For extra value the quoting and dequoting functions should not cons a string if they don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_c.htm

> The control-string argument to format is actually a format control.
> That is, it can be either a format string or a function, for example a
> function returned by the formatter macro.

So you can do:

```
(defmacro frmt (control-string)
  (let ((str (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "~m" control-string "~~m"))) 
    `(formatter ,str)))
```

Now:

```
(format t (frmt "~m~A") 1)
```

outputs:

```
~m1
NIL
```

This way you don't have to modify the control string directly.
You do have to modify the call to `format` to include `frmt`.